# How to clear the cache on laravel 9 server

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, caching, laravel-9

Does any one know how to clear the cache on laravel -9 on server
I tried it and it took me to a 404 error page

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
 
    return "Cleared!";
 
 });
```

and

```
Route::get('clear',[SiteController::class,'clear']);
```

```
public function clear()

    {

    \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    \Artisan::call('config:clear');
    \Artisan::call('config:cache');
    \Artisan::call('view:clear');
 
    return "Cleared!";

    }
```

I have tried these 2 code, both are not working. and My new updates are not showing up on the site also

please help me
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Error 404 because your route is cached. if you have terminal access to the server. then execute php artisan route:clear in server

Comment: The route cache is also stored in file `boostrap/cache/routes-v7.php` so you can manually delete that file from your server as well

Comment: @apokryfos It's not working

Comment: not exacly sure what is not working? If you delete that file you've cleared the route (and only the route) cache. There's no way that does not work unless you've deleted the wrong file

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add these code to `web.php`

```
Route::get('config', function () {
\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
\Artisan::call('storage:link');
\Artisan::call('view:clear');
\Artisan::call('route:clear');
\Artisan::call('config:clear');
dd("Success..! OK");});
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1

Answer (score 0):

be aware of the danger of this approach, if someone get the url of this route, they could clear your entire server's cache at will.

instead use a QueueJob or a Schedule, if your are using CI/CD you can also invoke those command everytime you deploy